# In Android Studio, I am getting this error in "doInBackground method"

Tags: java, android

Here First getWeather method execute which execute DownloadTask method and there when some null value is passed by user and th link in getWeather is not correct then in doInBackground method while getting Input stream it shows fatal error.

```
package com.ssd.weatherapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    TextView resultTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

     }

    public void getWeather (View view){
        try {
            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

            String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(editText.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

            task.execute("https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName + "&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02\n");

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("info","1st one");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not find weather :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;



            try{
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                InputStream in =  urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while(data != -1){
                    char current =(char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not find weather :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
                Log.i("info",weatherInfo);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

                String msg ="";

                for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonPart= arr. getJSONObject(i);

                   String main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                   String description =jsonPart.getString("description");

                   if(!main.equals("") && !description.equals("")){
                       msg += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";
                   }
                }

                if(!msg.equals("")){
                    resultTextView.setText(msg);
                }else{
                    Log.i("info","3rd one");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not find weather :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("info","4th one");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not find weather :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The error occurring when I don't type anything in textView and it is sent to downloadTask Class and instead of showing exception and giving a toast, app crashes and shows this error :

```
2020-06-16 00:01:46.117 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.ssd.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:74)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.ssd.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.529 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-06-16 00:01:47.530 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

    --------- beginning of crash
2020-06-16 00:01:47.532 7948-7986/com.ssd.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.ssd.weatherapp, PID: 7948
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:393)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:117)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:280)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:270)
        at com.ssd.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
        at com.ssd.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-06-16 00:01:47.919 7948-7976/com.ssd.weatherapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7740080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdfb95320)
```

(note: when button clicked it runs getWeather method)
But if I give correct value in textView it works fine.

Comment: `Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` in practice means that you can't display a `Toast` from a background thread.

Comment: You cannot do in background anything that is accessing UI in any way because then it should be blocking the UI until the end of the background task execution, and this is not allowed. Remove `Toast` from `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked when I removed the Toast from doInBackground and also got the reason :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you have to be mindful of what runs on the main (UI) thread and what runs on background threads.

`AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` runs in a background thread so you cannot do anything UI related there, like showing a `Toast` or updating views.

---

A few other things to be mindful of are:

- `AsyncTask` has now been deprecated and will not be available eventually.
- Inner classes in java should be static (unless intended) to avoid leaking their parent class. In your code above the `AsyncTask` will prevent the GC from clearing the `Activity` reference if it was still running after the `Activity` has finished.
- Similar to the previous point, the app would crash if the activity was destroyed before the `AsyncTask` finishes. Because when the `AsyncTask` finishes and tries to update the UI in `onPostExecute` there will be no views (null) to update.